# Is this login method secure

Tags: php, mysql, security

I did the following administrator login for a client's website, and I just wanted to ask if this method is secure, I use a userID cookie check along with a "is the administrator online" entry in the db that i also check for security reasons.

Sorry if my formatting is bad, i will accept any tips, please have patience with me, I'm a newbie programmer that just entered the phase "First projects for clients".

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['usr']) && isset($_POST['pwd'])){
    $usr=$_POST['usr'];
    $pwd=md5($_POST['pwd']);

    $userquery="SELECT * FROM nexus_administrators WHERE user='".$usr."';";
    $execuser=mysqli_query($con,$userquery);
    $usrnum= mysqli_num_rows($execuser);

    $pwdquery="SELECT * FROM nexus_administrators WHERE pwd='".$pwd."';";
    $execpwd=mysqli_query($con,$pwdquery);
    $pwdnum= mysqli_num_rows($execpwd);

    $query="SELECT adminid FROM nexus_administrators WHERE pwd='".$pwd."' AND user='".$usr."';";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $uid= $row['adminid'];

    echo $uid;
    if($usrnum==1 && $pwdnum==1){
        setcookie("uid", $uid, time()+3600*1000);
        $puthimonline= "UPDATE nexus_administrators SET isOn=1 WHERE adminid='".$uid."';";
        mysqli_query($con,$puthimonline);
        header('Location: adminpanel.php');

    }


}

//Ai n-ai cookie dai la poarta
if (!isset($_COOKIE['uid'])){
    echo " INTRUS !!!!";
    echo " </br> Zbori sau o s**i pe ciuperca";
}else{
    //te verific si-n baza
    $query= "SELECT * FROM nexus_administrators WHERE adminid='".$_COOKIE['uid']."' AND isOn=1;";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!= 1){
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        if(isset($_GET['log'])){
            $puthimoffline= "UPDATE nexus_administrators SET isOn=0 WHERE adminid='".$_COOKIE['uid']."';";
            mysqli_query($con,$puthimoffline);
            header('Location: index.php');
        }



        echo "hello my dear admin";



        echo"
        <a href='adminpanel.php?log=0'> Log Out</a>";


    };
}



?>
```

Comment: What's your definition of secure?

Comment: SQL Injection in 3...2...1...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This is better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: Nothing is 100% secure. Using `md5()` is not a good idea these days, there are more efficient hashing algorithms like `bcrypt` etc now. You should also use parameterised queries, then once you've done all those things - try and break it yourself!

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that there was a different section for this

Comment: It's 100% unsecure.
Use prepared statements, and remove logical errors. F.e. you dont need first two selects

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'm writing it down

Comment: This code allows a user to log in if their username matches any record and the password matches any record. I think you would want to match on both for one user!

Comment: After a redirect, always `exit()`, otherwise you'll have strange race-condition effects. PHP will cheerfully carry on executing code after a `header()` call, since it does not know what a `Location` header actually does.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is flawed. There are several problems.

- It makes no sense to count the number of users that have the same password (second query)
- a md5 hash is not sufficient for storing the passwords. If an attacker gets access to the database, he can easily find the passwords. You must use a salt.
- save isonline in the database makes no sense. If the user does not log off, access remains granted forever in the database.
- You save the userid in the cookie. It's not secure, because it is easy to spoof.
- last but not least your code is open for SQL injection (once from a query string variable, and two instances from cookies).